# NSTableView align to the right of the window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

Ok, I have an NSTableView in my window in Interface Builder and I'd like it to be at a constant width of 250 (even when the user resizes the window !!!). I'd also want it to stay on the right side, like a side panel or so. I also want the cells to stay at the exact same width.
I have added an image below. I guess there are some options in Interface Builder right ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to the metrics pane in Interface Builder and set your table view autosizing options like in the picture below

[image]

In this way, your table view will stick to the right side and not grow (i.e., will keep its width).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the metrics pane when I click the table view. When I switch from the Size Inspector to another panel i see the metrics pane flashing up, but then it miraculously disappears.

Comment: Ok I found out why I do not have the metrics pane -> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3835237?start=0&tstart=0